# How replace chars between two strings

Tags: php

I have text like:

```
$text = 'number="1" body="Are you "special" man?" name="man" code="1"
         number="2" body="Hi said "HaHaHa""?" name="man" code="2"'
```

I working on it but without any success. I need to replace all `"` with `#` in body section. Can somebody help me with this?

So result should be:

```
$text = 'number="1" body="Are you #special# man?" name="man" code="1"
         number="2" body="Hi said #HaHaHa#?" name="man" code="2"'
```

Comment: if you do that, you'll have a problem with the string!

Comment: It can be replaced with # or sth else

Comment: so you want to change `"HaHaHa"` to `#HaHaHa#` ?

Comment: Yes, shoud be like #HaHaHa#

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex solution with `preg_replace` and `preg_replace_callback` functions:

```
$text = 'number="1" body="Are you "special" man?" name="man" code="1"
         number="2" body="Hi said "HaHaHa""?" name="man" code="2"';

$text = preg_replace_callback('/(body=")(.*)(?=" name)/', function($m) {
    return $m[1] . preg_replace('/"+/', '#', $m[2]);
}, $text);

print_r($text);
```

The output:

```
number="1" body="Are you #special# man?" name="man" code="1"
         number="2" body="Hi said #HaHaHa#?" name="man" code="2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going along the same lines as [RomanPerekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest):

```
preg_match_all('/body="(.*?)" /', $text, $matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $find) {
    $text = str_replace($find, str_replace('"', '#', $find), $text);
}
```

Get all of the `body="something"` and replace any `"` that are inside the `""`.  Replace the original `body="something"` with the new one.